# how to center logo in the navbar

Tags: html, css, center

I want "THE NAV" to be displayed in the center of the navbar for mobile view and want the hamburger menu icon on the far right side.
how do i do this?
I tried `.logo justify-content: center` but nothing changed

If anyone would care to explain this to me I would be super grateful, I have tried finding a solution myself by using google but as I'm quite new to this I haven't been able to find a fix for my problem because I'm really not sure what to search for to fix my problem

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #5d4954;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #5d4954;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <h4>The Nav</h4>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: `.logo{margin: auto; padding-left:50px;}`

Answer (score 0):

So thing is: Display Flex distributes space between divs evenly. This means your logo and your burger bove geht the same space and justify-content then placees them next to each other with 50% width.

What you need to do is: Take the burger out of the equation for the flexbox. You can do this by placing it absolute (with position: absolute) and then you just have to tell it a right-value of e.g. 40px

```css
//CSS
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #5d4954;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #5d4954;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;

  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
//HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>NAVIGATION</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <h4>The Nav</h4>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="nav.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```